# Url Shortner in Codeinghter

Tags: codeigniter

I am using codeinghter, in which urls are so long like

`http://handysites.com.au/admin-new/en/clienth/dashboard?id=check-tab`

i want to short it like above link must be

`http://handysites.com.au/`

and remaining part become hide, is it possible?

Comment: "hide" seems pretty ambiguous. Do you want your URL to be fixed to `http://handysites.com.au/` all the time?

Comment: yes, what ever has been concatenated with it , no matter

Comment: you can use htacess for that @FarooqKhan

Comment: how can I? plz give me some idea

Comment: If you're not familiar with `.htaccess`, you might want to put the entire CodeIgniter views into `<iframe>` and your URL won't be changed.

Comment: maybe you want to create a SPA(Single page application)

Answer (score 1):

yes its possible
codeigniter provides routes
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html
its in `application/config/routes.php`

```
$route['http://handysites.com.au/(:any)'] = "http://handysites.com.au/admin-new/en/clienth/dashboard/$1";
```

Comment: Thanks Ijaz bhai,
but the problem is , my routing file does work, links not updated, I don,t know why

Comment: ok routes is working properly i think you are calling
http://handysites.com.au/admin-new/en/clienth/dashboard/$1
on click or from submitting
what you need to do is
call http://handysites.com.au/(:any)'
on click

Comment: Ijaz bhai still not working , i don,t know why.....comeplete code line is

`$route['http://handysites.com.au/(:any)'] = "http://handysites.com.au/admin-new/en/clienth/dashboard/$1";
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = '';`

Comment: can you give me link how you are calling method

Comment: this is the url i want to short it and make it

Comment: then call  
mauqe.com/dashboard
from link and make it in routes
$route['mauqe.com/dashboard'] ="mauqe.com/admin/en/clienth/dashboard "